# How to Test EMA Crossover obtained from pandas python in MS Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, moving-average

Exponential Moving Average is explained here in this link:  http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/ema.asp

I have used the following code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
#
aapl_df = web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime(2016, 03, 31))
aapl_df['SMA5'] = aapl_df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=5,center=False).mean()
aapl_df['SMA20'] = aapl_df['Adj Close'].rolling(window=20,center=False).mean()
aapl_df['EMA5'] = aapl_df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=5).mean()
aapl_df['EMA20'] = aapl_df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=20).mean()
#aapl_df['EMA20'] = aapl_df['Adj Close'].ewm(span=20,min_periods=20).mean() # commented to explain the min_periods
# Plot price vs various mean
aapl_df['2016'][['Adj Close', 'SMA20','EMA5', 'EMA20']].plot(figsize=(12,8));
# Reset the index
aapl_df = aapl_df.reset_index()
#Replace nan values with 0
aapl_df = aapl_df.fillna(0)
#
if aapl_df['Adj Close'].iloc[len(aapl_df)-1] > aapl_df['SMA20'].iloc[len(aapl_df)-1]:
    print  "20 day trendUP"
#==============================================================================
# Since the EMAs represent continuous functions, there is a crossing when,
# for a given row, (EMA_5 is less than EMA_20) and (the previous EMA_5 is
# greater than the previous EMA_20) -- or vice versa.
#==============================================================================
ema_previous5 = aapl_df['EMA5'].shift(1)
ema_previous20 = aapl_df['EMA20'].shift(1)
ema_crossing1 = (aapl_df['EMA5'] < aapl_df['EMA20']) & (ema_previous5 > ema_previous20)
ema_crossing2 = (aapl_df['EMA5'] > aapl_df['EMA20']) & (ema_previous5 < ema_previous20)
ema_crossing = ema_crossing1 | ema_crossing2
ema_crossing_dates = aapl_df.loc[ema_crossing, 'Date']
print ema_crossing_dates
```

.
My Doubts:

1) If I look into aapl_df, the first 19 values for the column SMA20 are blank. But the same is no so for EMA20 (unless I set the option min_periods=20 for calculation of aapl_df ). Don't we need the first 19 values for calculation of EMA20 ? This doubt has arisen becos, in another software that I am using, for the calculation of EMA20, the value of EMA20 for the first 19 days show up as blank.

2) Is the EMA calculation in pandas using the ewm method also on rolling basis. Which means, is the EMA20 for 2016-03-31 based only on the last 20 values (for 2016-03-03 to 2016-03-31 ie; index 41-60 in aapl_df). Likewise is the EMA20 for 2016-03-30 based only on the last 20 values (for 2016-03-02 to 2016-03-30 ie; index 40-59 in aapl_df)? This doubt has arisen becos the method "rolling" is explicitly mentioned in calculation of SMA with the window option, but not so for calculation of EMA.

3) I want to test the correctness of EMA20 in MS Excel for the same data. How can I do this ?

4) I am presently using the logic mentioned above to calculate the EMA crossover, Is there any alternative method of doing it using pandas ?

Thank You.